# Laravel - Inserting Empty Value to Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, loops

Hello I would like to insert a null value to my database but i have no clue how to do it is giving an error

How to insert an empty value to input text and set it to null to database, as I do this Im having an error because the rows of the database does not have a value. how can I do this without an error.

here is my ***error***

As you can see I have a foreach loop so inserting 1 input text value returns nothing on the database.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title'
>   cannot be null (SQL: insert into `awards` (`title`, `description`,
>   `awards_image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , a:0:{},
>   2018-11-28 10:29:35, 2018-11-28 10:29:35))

my ***Controller***

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'nullable',
        'description' => 'nullable',
        'awards_image.*' =>  'image|nullable|max:1999'
    ]);
    $awards = [];
    if ($request->has('awards_image'))
    {   
        //Handle File Upload


        foreach ($request->file('awards_image') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/awards_images',$fileNameToStore);
            array_push($awards, $fileNameToStore);
        }

        $fileNameToStore = serialize($awards);
    }
    else
    {
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }


foreach ($awards as $key => $values) {
            $awardsContent = new Award;
            $awardsContent->title = $request->title[$key];
            $awardsContent->description = $request->description[$key];
            $awardsContent->awards_image = $values;
            $awardsContent->save();
            }

}
```

Comment: Make your database table nullable as i've explained in previous question.

Comment: if attribute has no value put empty string like `' '` it's allows to null.

Comment: @Gabrielle how can I do that? please help me with that syntax thns

Comment: @SagarGautam can i do that without `php artisan migrate:refresh` ?

Comment: @Gabrielle, the empty string and `null` are two very different things.

Comment: @Gabrielle i like your logic sir, but how can i do that in the foreach loop section can you kindly help me please thanks

Comment: @Gabrielle  ok can we go to the string ` '' ` ?how can we do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Inserting empty to Input Form and Insert Null Value to Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53511239/laravel-inserting-empty-to-input-form-and-insert-null-value-to-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to change the table then try this:

```
foreach ($awards as $key => $values) {
        $awardsContent = new Award;
        $awardsContent->title = !empty($request->title[$key]) ? $request->title[$key] : '';
        $awardsContent->description = $request->description[$key];
        $awardsContent->awards_image = $values;
        $awardsContent->save();
        }

}
```

Some more info in `empty()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

If you are happy to change the table the create a migration where this is in up

```
Schema::table('awards', function(Blueprint $table) {

    $table->string('title')->nullable()->change();

});
```

of course you will have to change this to what you have already but the important part is `->nullable()->change();` the rest of the line should be the same as your initial migration.

Some more info on migration changes:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#modifying-columns

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Josh this is a lot of info. I hope you will reply if ever i need helps on this code thank you very much

Comment: how about the Image @Josh ? how can I make that null too?

Comment: you can use the same for the awards_image as the title just change the code to match the awards_image

Comment: I mean it is $fileNameStorage .. i think it will be different in approach dont ya think sir?

Comment: last problem is when I insert `Title` and `Description` and leave Input File null , i cant insert any data why is that?

Comment: You are using the `$awards` variable for foreach but you are not setting anything to it. try changing `$fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';` to `$awards[] = 'noimage.jpg';`

Comment: it does not work sir, why is that .. im having this last issue with this foreach loop :( I also need to insert title and description and LEAVE input file alone. but as im doing that .. it does not insert any data

Comment: Wait sir it works ! but the title is the same value as description

Comment: sit it works but lastly the  `TITLE  ` value is the same as  `DESCRIPTION ` value .. like for example, I insert **dummy 1** in the title  then the description will also be ""dummy 1** .

Comment: try making it 'test title' and 'test description' Also if you are adding multiple with not image it will not work

Comment: HAHA it works sir time wasted just a typo error THANK YOU you saved my time today

Comment: sir how can I make this image null or no value  `$paxSafetyContent->paxsafety_image =  !empty($value) ? $value : '';`  is this code correct?

Comment: Yeah if the value is empty it will be `''`

Comment: sir please refer to this [Link for: Image Null Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514339/laravel-inserting-empty-string-or-null-images-to-the-database) for you to help me more

Answer (score 0):

Make a new migration

```
php artisan make:migration fix_title_in_table_awards --table=awards
```

Then in the migration created first drop the column, and then recreate the column making it nullable..

```
Schema::table('awards', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColum('title');
});

Schema::table('awards', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('title')->nullable();
});
```

Take care of this action because you will lost all the data in that column...maybe you can copy the actual values of title to another column untill you make the change...